# Header is not accessible

Tags: wpf

I am trying to redefine the style of a HeaderedContentControl. Here the style I put together looking up at few examples in Internet.

```
 <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Row="0" />
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Row="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

At designtime, I get an error on TemplateBinging Header, saying that Header is not accessible.
Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Usage

```
 <HeaderedContentControl Header="Header" Content="Content" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">

</HeaderedContentControl>
```